# What is the value of bootstrapping residuals?

Tags: r, regression, self-study, inference, bootstrap

I have come across a question in Gelman - Regression and Other Stories that asks;

> Using data of interest to you, fit a model of interest.
> (a) Simulate replicated datasets and visually compare to the actual data

Using information contained within the chapter I take this as being fit a model:

```
y = X β + error
```

compute residuals of this model

```
r = y − X β
```

and bootstrap these residuals to form new fitted values of form:

```
y_boot = X β + r_boot
```

I then compare `y_boot` to the y value of the original data.

I have done this with the following `R` code below using the BostonHousing data from package mlbench;

```R
library(mlbench)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)

data("BostonHousing")
df <- BostonHousing %>% mutate(ID = 1:nrow(.))

gen_datasets <- function(n_sims){
  
  gen_boot.res <- function(){
    fit <- lm(medv ~ crim, df)
    boot_res <- sample(fit$residuals, replace = TRUE)
    fit_boot <- predict(fit) + boot_res
    return(fit_boot)
  }
  output <- tibble()
  for(i in 1:n_sims){
    output[1:506, paste('Sim_', i ,sep = '')] = gen_boot.res()
  }
  return(output)
  }
  
df.plot <- cbind(df %>% select(medv, ID, crim), gen_datasets(20)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = 4:ncol(.),
               names_to = 'sims',
               values_to = 'vals') 

ggplot(df.plot, aes( crim, medv, group = 1)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  stat_smooth(aes(x = crim, y = vals), method = "lm",se = TRUE, formula = y ~ x) +
  facet_wrap(~fct_relevel(sims, str_c('Sim_' , c(1:20))), scales = 'free_y')

ggplot(df.plot, aes( crim, medv, group = sims)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  stat_smooth(aes(x = crim, y = vals),
              method = "lm",se = FALSE, 
              formula = y ~ x, geom = 'line',
              alpha = .5, colour = 'red'
              )
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: The `fit_boot` calculation looks fishy: why not just add the permuted residuals to the fitted values as computed using `predict(fit)`?  What testing have you done of your code?  What plots have you produced to check that the code is doing what you think it does?  How have you compared your simulated data to the original data?

Comment: It looks like your `fit_boot` line is not adding the constant term (`fit$coefficients[[1]]`).  Since the constant term is estimated as 24.03 (when I just did it), that would explain why your residuals are clustering around some number pretty close to 24.  Better, in general, to use @whuber's recommendation of `predict(fit)`, though, as it's less prone to user error!

Comment: Thanks, both. I have edited the question with the updates you suggest. However, I'm still confused as to why this is still a valuable exercise. Although the graph now looks less clustered, comparing the original values from the data to the new fit_boot values doesn't reveal much to me. I'm not clear why this is a valuable thing to do. The only thing I have noticed when comparing histograms is that the fit_boot values appear to be closer to normally distributed than the original values.

Comment: One draw from the bootstrap distribution doesn't necessarily tell you a whole lot.  (This is why the question refers to "datasets" in the *plural.*) You have to decide *how* you want to compare such a draw to the original data and then you need to assess how this comparison varies from one bootstrap draw to another.  A nice approach is the "data lineup" in which you portray a small multiple of, say, 20 datasets of which one is the original and the others are bootstrap (or permutation) variations.  `facet_wrap` will make short work of this.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I've updated the question. 

I think I have bootstrapped the data properly and produced 20 different datasets and produced the 'data lineup' as you describe it. I'm just using a scatterplot to see how the bootstrapped data compares to the original data as is hinted at in the question... but maybe that is where I am thinking about this wrong...? Because I still don't understand what the plots are telling me as it does not seem to vary much at all. Should I be looking at sample statistics or something else?

Comment: You've done a great job: but you're not bootstrapping yet.  After adding the resampled residuals to the predicted values, *you must re-fit the model.*  One of the better things you can do in the panel plots is to depict the refitted-model.  *That's* what you want to study, because it indicates how uncertain that model fit might be.

Comment: Okok, I think we are getting somewhere! I've edited the question to reflect current thinking... it was a mistake to not re-fit the model as that is what produces the new datasets. I think I see the value of this now, as simply refitting a linear model to the original data will not produce a different line, whereas, bootstrapping the residuals adds a different degree of variation to the data every iteration and gives you an idea of how you would expect the model to vary given new data? I plotted the panel chart, however, I thinkjust overlaying the models gives a good indication of the variance

Comment: Yes, both plots are helpful.  The panels help you see how the bootstrapped *data* are changing while the overlay helps you see how the *models* change.  In `ggplot2` you can usually generate both forms of these plots by starting with the second and then simply replotting it with a `+ facet_wrap` function added.  There's no need to formulate two separate plotting commands.  However, I don't see a definite question in your post any more (the title is too vague).

Comment: I've been fiddling but I can't quite get the data to do what I think you suggest. Are you saying that each facet plot displays a permutation of the data with all regression lines overlaid on each facet plot? I think my question has been answered with my understanding explained in the above comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This reply is primarily comments aimed at creating a reliable workflow for such an analysis.**

The suggested procedure is this:

1. **Prepare the data** by creating a complete dataset with just the needed variables and no missing values.  This reduces the chances of errors when the software (perhaps silently) removes incomplete cases.
2. **Fit the model.**  Encapsulate the fitting process in a procedure or function for reuse.
3. **Perform the bootstrapping** in a loop by

   - creating a bootstrap sample
   - fitting the sample
   - storing the sample and any essential results of the fit (coefficients, *etc.*)
4. **Examine the results** both visually and with statistical summaries.

   - Include the original data and fit for comparison.
   - Consider a "data lineup" for comparing a small set of bootstrap samples to the data.
5. Based on this examination return to step (2) or step (1) and **repeat as needed.**

---

The "data lineup" is a way to assess the "significance" of any result, visually and quickly.  If you present, say, 20 versions of the data and they all differ from the data in some clear way, you have visual evidence that the data differ from the procedure you used to generate those 20 versions.  This is the statistical analog of the familiar police lineup used to identify a crime suspect by viewing that suspect within a group of comparable people.

**Some tips:**

- **Do not rely on the graphics software to perform your analysis.**  Use it to display the results of your analysis.
- **Encapsulate the basic operations** of fitting a model, extracting its results, and plotting those results.  This helps ensure consistent, reliable processing of the data and the bootstrap samples.  See the `analyze`, `predict.`, and `residuals.` functions in the `R` code below.

**The `R` code below illustrates the foregoing points.**  In particular, notice the ease of bootstrapping: it's just a loop over two lines of code,

```R
    X$medv <- y.hat + sample(residuals.(fit), replace=TRUE)
    y <- predict.(analyze(X), newdata=W)
```

The first line performs the bootstrap sampling while the second redoes the fit and extracts the information of interest (in this case, y-values for the graph of the fitted values).

**This code produced the following plots** at step (4).
[image: Figure 1]

Notice that this model is not a simple linear relationship between `medv` and `crim`: I have fit a more suitable logarithmic one.  The opportunity to fit *exactly the right model* is the main reason not to rely on the graphics program to do the fitting for you: it often will not be flexible enough.
[image: Figure 2]

This is the same plot, displayed with one panel per iteration.
[image: Figure 3]

This is the same as the previous plot, displayed now on a logarithmic axis. Much more can be seen now.  Some outliers are evident in the upper right corner of the data (Panel 20) and there's some evidence of positive skewness in the responses -- perhaps even bimodality.  These both suggest avenues for further analysis.

Finally, **`R` users might appreciate the effective use of the Grammar of Graphics approach to visualization** (as implemented in `ggplot2`): the graphical display is described once (with almost no customization of scales) and then redrawn multiple times with added variations.  This economy of expression helps assure consistency in the output.

I hope this small example illustrates the merits of the approach suggested by the original exercise.

```R
library(ggplot2)
#
# Access and prepare the data.
#
library(mlbench)
data(BostonHousing)
df <- subset(BostonHousing, select=c(medv, crim))
df <- subset(df, complete.cases(df)) # Essential for handling missing data!
#
# Perform the original analysis.
#
analyze <- function(df) lm(medv ~ log(crim), df)
predict. <- function(f, ...) predict(f,  ...)
residuals. <- function(f, ...) residuals(f, ...)
fit <- analyze(df)
#
# Prepare for bootstrapping.
#
n.boot <- 20
set.seed(17)
y.hat <- predict.(fit)
n <- length(residuals.(fit))
W <- data.frame(crim = exp(seq(log(min(df$crim)), log(max(df$crim)), length.out=101)))
#
# Obtain bootstrap samples.
#
B.boot <- lapply(1:n.boot, function(i) {
  X <- cbind(data.frame(Iteration = i), df)
  if(i < n.boot) {
    # This is one draw from the bootstrap distribution
    X$medv <- y.hat + sample(residuals.(fit), replace=TRUE)
    y <- predict.(analyze(X), newdata=W)
    status <- "Bootstrap"
  } else {
    # The last time through, just store the data and its analysis.
    y <- predict(fit, newdata=W)
    status <- "Data"
  }
  list(Data = cbind(X, data.frame(Status = status)), 
       Fit = cbind(data.frame(Iteration = i, Status = status, medv = y), W))
})
#
# Prepare for post-processing by assembling the results into data frames.
#
Points <- do.call(rbind, lapply(B.boot, function(l) l[["Data"]]))
Fits <- do.call(rbind, lapply(B.boot, function(l) l[["Fit"]]))
#
# Display versions of the plot.
#
G <- ggplot(Points, aes(crim, medv, group=Iteration)) + 
  geom_point(aes(fill=Status), shape=21, alpha=1/2) + 
  geom_line(aes(color=Status), data=Fits, size=0.95) + 
  ggtitle("All Data, Original and Bootstrapped")

print(G)
print(H <- G + facet_wrap(~ Iteration))
#
# More displays as suggested by review.
#
print (H + scale_x_log10() + 
         theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90)) +
         ggtitle("Results on a Logarithmic X Scale"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for an incredibly insightful and detailed reply.